# Can Levenshein distance prevent password abuse?

Tags: python, authentication, flask

Learning about passwords by writing an app around flask's auth utilities. I'ved crammed all the approaches I can think of in one function cleanpassword(). Later I will decide which ones are more trouble than they are worth.

This is the fragment in question. The rest of the function is below for context.
I downloaded a list of the worst passwords known to man (in English -- I bet the lists for others are just as funny). I archive each password as it is used. There is a timestamp if I ever need to allow reuse after a while. The archived passwords are stored hashed because seeing a users last five passwords would make it pretty easy to guess what his next five will be or what he uses on another site. The historically bad passwords are in plain text.

Storing them plain allows the use of Levenshein distance to prevent trivial modification of bad passwords ('football' 'f00tball' and 'futball!') are all treated the same.

```
#    # are they on the list of 10k really bad passwords?
#    if BadPasswords.query.filter(BadPasswords.baddie == password).first():
#        flash('Password '+ password +' is on the list of really bad passwords.','error')
#        return False

    # are close to the list of 10k really bad passwords?
    badwords = BadPasswords.query.all()
    for b in badwords:
        if lev_distance(b.baddie, password) < levenshtein_limit:
        flash('Password '+ password +' is on or near the list of really bad passwords.','error')
        return False

    # are they on the list old passwords?
    if bcrypt.check_password_hashpassword in OldPasswords.query.all():
        flash('Password '+ password +' is on the list of previous passwords.','error')
        return False
```

So the question is, can I use a similar edit distance test to prevent reuse of originally acceptable passwords? I think the answer is no, but it is hard to prove a negative -- particularly when authorization technology get very deep very close to shore. My understanding is elementary on a good day.

```
    # check for safe password

from password_strength import PasswordPolicy
from Levenshtein import distance as lev_distance
from app import bcrypt, db
from models import BadPasswords, OldPasswords
from extensions import environ

forgive = environ.get('FORGIVE_BAD_PASSWORDS')
#forgive = True

levenshtein_limit = environ['LEVENSHTEIN_LIMIT']


# class BadPasswords(db.Model):
#     __tablename__ = 'BadPasswords'
#     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
#     baddie = db.Column(db.String(25)) 

# class OldPasswords(db.Model):
#     __tablename__='OldPasswords'
#     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
#     oldie = db.Column(db.String(255)) 
#     created = db.Column(db.DateTime)


policy = PasswordPolicy.from_names(
    length     = environ['PASSWORD_LENGTH'],
    uppercase  = environ['PASSWORD_REQUIRE_UPPERCASE'],
    nonletters = environ['PASSWORD_REQUIRE_NON_LETTERS'],
    strength   =(environ['PASSWORD_REQUIRE_STRENGTH'], environ['PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTROPY_BITS'])
)

def cleanpassword(password,verify):
    # forgive bad passwords for debugging
    if forgive:
        return True

    # do they match?
    if not password == verify:
        flash ("Passwords don't match")
        return False

#    are they on the list of 10k really bad passwords?
#    if BadPasswords.query.filter(BadPasswords.baddie == password).first():
#        flash('Password '+ password +' is on the list of really bad passwords.','error')
#        return False

    # are close to the list of 10k really bad passwords?
    badwords = BadPasswords.query.all()
    for b in badwords:
        if lev_distance(b.baddie, password) < levenshtein_limit:
        flash('Password '+ password +' is on or near the list of really bad passwords.','error')
        return False

    # are they on the list old passwords?
    if bcrypt.check_password_hashpassword in OldPasswords.query.all():
        flash('Password '+ password +' is on the list of previous passwords.','error')
        return False

    # use the quality tests      
    test = policy.test(password)
    if test:
        for t in test:
            fault = t.name()
            if fault == 'length':
                flash('Password needs at least '+ str(t.length) +' letters.','error')
            if fault == 'uppercase':
                flash('Password needs at least '+ str(t.count)  +' upper-case letters.','error')
            if fault == 'nonletters':
                flash('Password needs at least '+ str(t.count)  +' non-letter characters.','error')
            if fault == 'strength':
                flash('Password needs more entropy.')
        return False

    # seems to have passed all the tests
    return True
```

Comment: [Password strength doesn't matter](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/your-pa-word-doesn-t-matter/ba-p/731984). You shouldn't be enforcing strength or composition requirements, you should be enforcing password managers and MFA. I rag on MS all the time and for good reason, but given that Active Directory is the most popular identity management platform by light years, this is one area I'm prepared to admit they know what they're talking about.

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/misc/password-policy-recommendations?view=o365-worldwide#password-guidelines-for-administrators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you?  Yes.  Should you?  Absolutely not.  Since you say you only know the basics, I'll explain.

### Hashing basics

As you said, stored passwords should always be hashed for safety.  I hope you're salting them as well as hashing - or maybe flask does it for you, I don't know.

For the hash function to be any good, it has to create essentially random output.  If you hash two values that differ only by a single character - like foobar and foobaz - the hash output should be completely different.  If all you have is the hashes, there's no way to tell whether the inputs are related (like foobar and foobaz) or completely different (like foobar and elephant).  Otherwise your hash function is not secure and your passwords can be compromised.

So the properties of a good hash function make hash values completely useless for levenstein distance or any other measures of similarity.  All relations between the inputs are destroyed by the hash.

### How it affects your approach

This means you can only run levenstein distance on unhashed (plaintext) passwords.  That solution is wrong for so many reasons.  Passwords should never be stored anywhere in plaintext (your bad passwords list is ok because you reject those as passwords).  Passwords should never be sent in plaintext.  Passwords should never be sent to the server at all under any conditions.  The password should only leave the client in an already hashed state.

If you follow this important rule then you can *only* runs password checks on the client side.  Client enters possible password, local code checks it's validity.  If it's ok, then password is hashed before being sent to server.  Server should never see the plaintext, or it can be compromised.

What you're attempting is impossible in this situation.  Your auth server stores previous passwords, hashed.  There's no way to compute a meaningful distance metric between hashed passwords and new password, either before or after hashing it.  Doesn't matter if you send hashed previous passwords to client, or send plaintext new password to server (VERY BAD).  Either way, you can't compute meaningful comparisons with hashed values.

### How it should be done

Hopefully your password checks are done client side - it's not clear where your sample code runs.  If server side, then stop immediately and rethink your design.  Passwords should never be sent to the server.

Even sending hashed passwords is insecure.  If my password is "foobar" which hashes to "vsfsevssdfsdga", and I send "vsfsevssdfsdga" to authenticate to the server every time, then I've accomplished nothing.  An attacker can snoop the magic token ""vsfsevssdfsdga" " and use it to gain access, defeating the purpose of hashing.

What you should really be doing is a challenge-response system where the client and server both know a shared secret (such as a hashed password) that's never exchanged directly.  Instead, the server sends a challenge like "send me the hash of your password, hashed with random string XYZ".  It works like this:

### Example

Take the example above : password foobar with hash "vsfsevssdfsdga".  Server stores "vsfsevssdfsdga" and computes hash ("vsfsevssdfsdga" + XYZ) = klojhsvndfb.  User enters foobar and client computes hash (hash (foobar) + XYZ) = klojhsvndfb.  Client sends klojhsvndfb.  The only data exchanged each login is XYZ from server to client, which is a random string each time ; and klojhsvndfb from client to server.  If an attacker learns the hash value klojhsvndfb, they can't use it to login in the future.  It's useless because the server will send a new challenge string instead of XYZ on every login attempt.

In this example, client and server still need to exchange "vsfsevssdfsdga" at the beginning for subsequent logins to work.  But there are protocols for client and server to establish a shared secret without directly exchanging any compromising info (i.e. someone can snoop on the entire conversation and still not be able to compute the shared secret).  If a password must be involved, probably the best approach is to create a secure shared secret between client and server, then store it client side encrypted with the user's password.  On login, client enters password to decrypt shared secret on local machine, then does challenge-response with server.

### Conclusion

That's the basic idea.  However please DO NOT try to implement this or any other type of authentication scheme yourself.  There are many, many subtle ways to screw up and compromise your security.  It's far better to use an established security library or framework to handle authentication for you.  Security is hard.  Trust me, it's very easy to get wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hashing the password before sending it from the client to server doesn't increase security much. If someone can intercept that, they can simply resend the hashed password.  The way to avoid sending passwords is with a challenge-response algorithm, where the password is used locally to calculate the response.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say that "passwords should never be sent to the server." Standard authentication schemes (e.g., how someone signs in to Google) sends the cleartext password to the server, so that the server can compare against the salted and hashed password. Secrecy of the data at motion is handled by public key encryption of the server communications (i.e., TLS). That way, the server never has to know anything usable as a password, so a server breach doesn't expose credentials.

Comment: Under a typical challenge-response scheme, such as you describe, the server has to have cleartext password equivalents. An attacker never sees "foobar," but if they can breach the server and get "vsfsevssdfsdga," then that's all they need to respond to any future challenge.

Comment: thanks Ed_. Your contribution makes sense and goes to the heart of the question, the ONLY ways to use edit-distance for this involves exposing a plain text password far more than is safe. The list of bad passwords being the exception because they are more bad than they are passwords. To the other posters (who may not have read the question) of course nobody would write their own auth system for real. The vast majority of my code is written to learn -- not to deploy.

Comment: +1: Super pedantic point: The client could *generate* every password of with edit-distance 1 (or even 2, if you are willing to commit some resources) from the password candidate, hash them all, and compare them to past hashes. Would detect most "You merely increased the number at the end by one" changes.

Comment: @josh-kelley it's better if server never has cleartext passwords.   TLS is not a solution.  There are many issues with TLS (corporate proxies, man in the middle attacks, compromised CAs, etc).  If plaintext ever hits the server or the wire (even in TLS) then it can be compromised.  A shared secret is better for exactly the reason you give: so exposing server data doesn't compromise user elsewhere.  Like it or not, users reuse passwords.